# Flask Redirect New Tab

Tags: python, flask

Does anyone know if flask redirect is able to open a link / URL in a new tab?

```
@app.route('/test')
def my_page():

  return redirect('http://mylink.com', 301)
```

I would like if the mylink website opened in a new tab, any insights?

Comment: I would think it would be easiest to have the link in the HTML open a new tab that points to `/test` and then let it redirect, like `<a href="http://www.example.com/test" target="_blank" >New Tab Link</a>`.  If someone navigates directly to `/test` is there a reason you would want them to open a new tab?

Comment: When the user visits /test and performs a POST request the python function actually creates the link and I would like the user to be sent to the link that is created and have it open in a new tab. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as I know that would not be a flask issue. You have to open a new tab within your [html code](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) or with [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript).

example:
`<a href="http://mylink.com" target="_blank">Link</a>`

The server has no power over what the browser does in this case.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use Python's webbrowser module to open a page, if you'd like to avoid getting into the HTML

```
import webbrowser

@app.route('/test')
def my_page():
    return webbrowser.open_new_tab('http://mylink.com')
```

Comment: Does anyone care to comment on why opening a new tab from within Flask is a bad idea?

Comment: This way doesent work if you upload your project in a Apache WSGI server.

Comment: Didn't quite work, getting "The view function did not return a valid response." error.

Comment: @JohnJiang Newer versions of Flask require you to `return` something in the response. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the new tab opens on the server machine, not on the client (the computer where I am actually accessing the site). Is there any fix for that?

Comment: @KrishnanShankar the fix would be to use Marco's answer :)

Comment: webbrowser will open a new tab on server side, he want it on client side

Comment: Sorry I try this answer .It's not working to me . Can you send me your source code

Answer (score 3):

If you're dealing with a `form` you can set `target="_blank"`

Answer (score 0):

A slight adjustment to @garettmd that fixes @John Jiang's issue:

```
import webbrowser
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for

@app.route("/test/")
def test():
    webbrowser.open("https://google.com")
    return redirect(url_for("index"))
```

This way we get to return a redirect (which we should probably do anyway) and we also get our new tab without "The view function did not return a valid response" error.

Comment: This did not work for me. I got a new tab with google but my redirect still loaded in the previous page.